# Extend existing Twisted Service with another Socket/TCP/RPC Service to get Service informations

Tags: twisted, twisted.web, twisted.internet

I'm implementing a Twisted-based Heartbeat Client/Server combo, based on [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52302-pyheartbeat-detecting-inactive-computers/). It is my first Twisted project.

Basically it consists of a UDP Listener (`Receiver`), who calls a listener method (`DetectorService.update`) on receiving packages. The DetectorService always holds a list of currently active/inactive clients (I extended the example a lot, but the core is still the same), making it possible to react on clients which seem disconnected for a specified timeout.

This is the source taken from the site:

```
UDP_PORT = 43278; CHECK_PERIOD = 20; CHECK_TIMEOUT = 15

import time
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.python import log

class Receiver(protocol.DatagramProtocol):
    """Receive UDP packets and log them in the clients dictionary"""

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (ip, port)):
        if data == 'PyHB':
            self.callback(ip)

class DetectorService(internet.TimerService):
    """Detect clients not sending heartbeats for too long"""

    def __init__(self):
        internet.TimerService.__init__(self, CHECK_PERIOD, self.detect)
        self.beats = {}

    def update(self, ip):
        self.beats[ip] = time.time()

    def detect(self):
        """Log a list of clients with heartbeat older than CHECK_TIMEOUT"""
        limit = time.time() - CHECK_TIMEOUT
        silent = [ip for (ip, ipTime) in self.beats.items() if ipTime < limit]
        log.msg('Silent clients: %s' % silent)

application = service.Application('Heartbeat')
# define and link the silent clients' detector service
detectorSvc = DetectorService()
detectorSvc.setServiceParent(application)
# create an instance of the Receiver protocol, and give it the callback
receiver = Receiver()
receiver.callback = detectorSvc.update
# define and link the UDP server service, passing the receiver in
udpServer = internet.UDPServer(UDP_PORT, receiver)
udpServer.setServiceParent(application)
# each service is started automatically by Twisted at launch time
log.msg('Asynchronous heartbeat server listening on port %d\n'
    'press Ctrl-C to stop\n' % UDP_PORT)
```

This heartbeat server runs as a daemon in background.

**Now my Problem**:

I need to be able to run a script "externally" to print the number of offline/online clients on the console, which the Receiver gathers during his lifetime (`self.beats`). Like this:

```
$ pyhb showactiveclients
3 clients online 
$ pyhb showofflineclients
1 client offline
```

So I need to add some kind of additional server (Socket, Tcp, RPC - it doesn't matter. the main point is that i'm able to build a client-script with the above behavior) to my DetectorService, which allows to connect to it from outside. It should just give a response to a request.

This server needs to have access to the internal variables of the running detectorservice instance, so my guess is that I have to extend the DetectorService with some kind of additionalservice.

After some hours of trying to combine the detectorservice with several other services, I still don't have an idea what's the best way to realize that behavior. So I hope that somebody can give me at least the essential hint how to start to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you already have the general idea of the solution here, since you already applied it to an interaction between `Receiver` and `DetectorService`.  The idea is for your objects to have references to other objects which let them do what they need to do.

So, consider a web service that responds to requests with a result based on the `beats` data:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class BeatsResource(Resource):
    # It has no children, let it respond to the / URL for brevity.
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self, detector):
        Resource.__init__(self)
        # This is the idea - BeatsResource has a reference to the detector,
        # which has the data needed to compute responses.
        self._detector = detector

    def render_GET(self, request):
        limit = time.time() - CHECK_TIMEOUT
        # Here, use that data.
        beats = self._detector.beats
        silent = [ip for (ip, ipTime) in beats.items() if ipTime < limit]
        request.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain')
        return "%d silent clients" % (len(silent),)

# Integrate this into the existing application
application = service.Application('Heartbeat')
detectorSvc = DetectorService()
detectorSvc.setServiceParent(application)
.
.
.
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.application.internet import TCPServer

# The other half of the idea - make sure to give the resource that reference 
# it needs.
root = BeatsResource(detectorSvc)
TCPServer(8080, Site(root)).setServiceParent(application)
```

Comment: thanks, I was able to solve my problem. However `TCPServer(8080, Site(root)).setServiceParent(application)` does not work (there is no such class within Twisted, and the TCPServer within Python has no `setServiceParent`. I'm using  `reactor.listenTCP(8080, Site(root))` in my code now, which works.

Comment: @ifischer: there is `t.a.i.TCPServer` class (it is generated dynamically). http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.application.internet.html